# Modifying an existing chemical formula to create a new product (formula) in an unrelated field

Tags: legal

I Modified an existing chemical formula by adding ingredients to create a new product formula (gel)} in a totally unrelated field. Would this be legal ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I've noticed that you've asked three different questions ([one](/q/10858/10011), [two](/q/10839/10011), and this one) with nearly-identical titles and subject matter. What makes this different from the previous ones you've asked? I refrained from asking before since there were minor changes between the first two, but this one seems like an exact duplicate.

Comment: Thx Matt, I also seem to have confused Bob T & Jeremy a little too lol. I added a little more detail to each question(sorry for  the redundancy). I have learned a lot of info & continue to learn from y'all answers...and I do appreciate the answers. I have learned that I can use a chemical formula that I purchase as I wish. 2. I can modify it to make a different product & resell it since the original formula's patent holder is paid because I purchased it. 3. I may be able to claim as a "trade secret" instead.  and I can't patent uses for my new formula & this is an awesome site!